# dynamic nested excel formula

Tags: excel, nested, formula

I work for an engineering organisation and have a large data set (50,000) of parts and sub assemblies.  My main objective is to work out the material portion of the sub-assemblies and ultimately the kits which are sold to the customers.  For example Part 1 is 50% aluminium 25% steel and 25% copper.

The attached image is an extract of the data which i am working with.

[image: Data]

Column A and B show the level of the parts (there are two examples here).
Column U shows the value by percentage of the higher level assembly.

What i want is a dynamic formula which will fill in row 2 AT to AZ with the material percentage that makes up the kit (for example aluminium in AT2 should state 77%) but i also require the formula to be dynamic and work for Part 2 where there is only 2 parts which make up the assembly.

The formula i have used is flawed (or i am unable to build upon it any further to make it work) and i am out of ideas of how to make a formula which is dynamic enough to input the data i need.  FYI i have a VBA programme which will input the formula into the required lines once i have a good formula.

Thank you in advance for your help
TJ

Comment: The practice in this forum is to provide your attempt (the formula you have tried). It often helps to understand your problem and avoid others making similar errors. Also this is not a free coding site but exists to help others with code or formulas they are trying to develop. Having said that, it seems from your data layout that a simple `SUMIFS` formula should do what you need. `SUMIFS` can use wild-cards in the criteria so you can use it to pick up all the sub-parts. If you can't get it to work, post back with your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to add a few columns and use SUMIF

1. Add an additional column for each material which is the contribution to the part for that material for each sub-assembly.  E.g. for Ally, add Ally1 which would be U * AT, this would be blank for row 2, but have .37 in row 3, .40 in row 4
2. Insert a new column in B, which shows the part name for each sub assembly, so in your example it would be blank for row 2, show "Part1" for rows 3-9, blank for row 10 and "Part2" for rows 11 and 12.  Hopefully you can do this through a formula or it is already in the data.
3. Now you can create your formula in the original material columns for each part, simply a sumif:

- Range is our new column B (which has the relevant part for each subassembly)
- Condition is the cell in A (which is the part we are trying to calculate for)
- Sum_Range is the new column we have created for each material in step 1, so for Ally it would be Ally1.

This should then give you the answers you want.

If you can't add the columns, then you will need to use a matrix formula with IF and SUMPRODUCT I think. I always find these painful to do and complicated to understand so hence suggest the simpler approach above.

**An aside**

If this was me I'd avoid using VBA to fill in the formulas - just because I like a column to either be all values or all the same formula.  The reason being if I later need to change a formula I can just copy it down over all the cells below.

To do that in this case I'd insert another column for each material, and use an IF statement to either pull in the current materials value (when it's a sub assembly) or use the formula in step 3 (when it is a part).